# Insert row into table when checkbox is checked

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access db to handle our product pricing.  One of my tables has all of our products in it with a yes/no, "checkbox",  field field to identify if we bulk that product. I have a separate table that handles our bulk product pricing. Currently when I want to set up a bulk product I add it to our products table, check off the bulked so it removes it from the non-bulk price query, then add the product# to the bulk products table.

I'm pretty new to VBA but what I want is when the "Bulked" field is checked it takes the product code for the current row and insert it into the product code field in Bulked Products. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can run an update query in VBA, but I suggest that you do not do it. It will involve you checking whether the record already exists in the bulk table, if it does exists, if it matches, and rewinding if someone clicks by mistake. I do not believe you need two tables, you just need a field to indicate that the product is bulk.

Comment: Should I put all of the bulk pricing fields in that table too?

Comment: It depends on how your pricing works and whether you have historical pricing. However, all products should be in the same table. It is possible that  product, units, price per unit in a table would suit, but if you have different prices for different quantities, you will need a price table.